# Is there any way to embed a video in a beamer presentation 2022?

Tags: beamer

As I understand it, there used to be ways to do this, but I can't find a way to do it after the abdication of flash.

Comment: E. g. SVG output instead of PDF, using package [`media4svg`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/media4svg/example/beamer-example-1.svg). Works well in all popular browsers across many platforms, F11 to put to fullscreen.

Comment: The `\movie` command from the `multimedia` package still works for me with regular mp4 videos. See the [beamer user's guide](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), sec 14.1.